# Unreadable text on http://stackexchange.com/sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com

On https://stackexchange.com/sites, a few of the sites have words that are impossible to read. For example, the words on the Biology block are so faint that it is almost impossible to read:

[image: Biology not readable]

This is also the case for Chemistry, although it is a little bit better:

[image]

Can we please fix this?

Comment: Just noticed: it's kinda hard to read the text for Web Applications too.

Comment: As far as I know the 503 page for Christianity.SE is also white text on almost-white background. I don’t know how to check whether this has been fixed…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice catch!

The Biology bubble background started out much darker (the same green that we use on the site itself), but then that clashed with the site logo... and I forgot to update the text color along with the background.